# Pydantic, polyfactory and ParamSpec

Tags: python, python-typing, pydantic, polyfactory

Using polyfactory to generate test pydantic objects, I end up with this to describe the typing, but it is not correct according to pyright (runtime, all is fine) and I wonder how to fix this.

```
from typing import Self

from polyfactory.factories.pydantic_factory import ModelFactory
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Parent(BaseModel):
    @classmethod
    def generate_test_instance[**P](cls, *_: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> Self:
        class Factorio(ModelFactory[cls]):
            __model__ = cls

        return Factorio.build(**kwargs)


class Child(Parent):
    param: str


Child.generate_test_instance()
```

The whole file is correct typing-wise, except the last line, complaining that `Param spec "P@generate_test_instance" has no bound value`.

To bind `P`, I could use `cls:Callable[P, T]` as first parameter of `generate_test_instance` but it breaks other things (typing wise): classmethod, use of cls in the __model__.

I understand that `P` needs to be bound, but I am not sure how.

Experimenting, I ended up with this option for the parent

```
class Parent2(BaseModel):
    @classmethod
    def generate_test_instance[T: BaseModel, **P](cls: Type[Callable[P, T]], *_: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        class Factorio(ModelFactory[T]):
            __model__ = cls

        return Factorio.build(**kwargs)
```

The child is happy (parameters are auto completed) but `__model__ = cls` in Parent2 gives a typing error (`Expected type expression but received "(**P@generate_test_instance) -> T@generate_test_instance"` respectively) which is not unexpected.

How could I get both of both worlds, ie. complete valid typing?